# hybrid or "mixed" networks

Tags: computer-architecture, computer-networks

I am a mathematician, and I am completely lay in the technical aspects of computer networks and computer architecture. I would like to know if there is any computer network or architecture, protocol, or whatever, which combines unidirectional links with bi-directional ones. If so, what are the practical advantages of this mixed architecture?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking for applications of directed graphs?

Comment: right, although not exactly directed graphs, but "mixed" graphs, where you allow directed arcs and undirected edges

Comment: Of course, you can always consider an edge as the union of two arcs, going in opposite directions, but this is not what I want. I am talking about truly bi-directional links, and truly uni-directional ones.

Comment: from an algorithmic standpoint what is the difference between a "truly bi-directional" link and a pair of uni-directional links going in opposite directions?  Also: are you sure you don't want hypergraphs instead of graphs?  Real computer networks are hypergraphs (some edges connect together more than two nodes.)  The hyper-edges are called "buses" in the computer network world.

Comment: OK, this information is useful, and I didn't know that. As I said before, I am completely lay in the technical aspects of networks. As for your question, the difference between a bi-directional link and a pair of opposite unidirectional links could be the cost, or maybe the kind of protocol that they use. I am just gessing, and I am asking you if this makes sense, or if there could be some advantage in forcing some links to be uni-directional, while allowing other links to carry information in both directions.

Comment: For example, suppose that some portion of the network has consistently high traffic. Is it sensible to implement that portion of a network with uni-directional links, in order to prevent collisions, while keeping the rest of the links bi-directional?